# Гранулированый select c последующим update

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, транзакции

Есть ли способы выполнения селекта с последующим апдейтом на выбранном наборе таким образом, чтобы между двумя запросами не выполнились запросы из других соединений, при этом не блокируя всю таблицу целиком?

Задача банальна - выбрать N записей, после чего все их обновить(несколько полей) так, чтобы между выборкой и обновлением те же самые записи не были выбраны параллельно в других соединениях.

Такие блокировки, как select for update не подходят, т.к они блокируют записи с индексом только если задано условие на "пространство" индексированного поля.

Есть ли какие-либо адекаватные методы решения этой задачи?

**UPDATE:**

Запросы выглядят следующим образом(все они - в триггерах):

```
START TRANSACTION ;

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempTable;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable AS(
            SELECT units.id AS id, units.authkey AS authkey
            FROM availablePublicUnitsView units
                LEFT JOIN media_info
                    ON units.id=media_info.unit_id AND media_info.media_id=mediaId
            WHERE media_info.media_id IS NULL
            LIMIT unitsCount
            #FOR UPDATE
        );

        UPDATE units SET reserved=true, last_usage_time=NOW(), reservation_hash=reservationHash
        WHERE id IN (SELECT id from TempTable) AND reserved=false;

        SELECT * FROM TempTable;

COMMIT ;
```

В SQL`е я не эксперт, так что если что-то в корне делаю неверно, буду рад услышать, что именно.

Comment: Можете поподробнее написать, почему для задачи выбрать + обновить именно эти выбранные записи вам не подходит select for update в транзакции?

Comment: Дело в том, что записи выбираются в случайном порядке, т.е до момента выборки неизвестно, какие значения индексированного поля будут выбраны. Вследствие чего для выполнения параллельного запроса на выборку блокируются все записи, т.к прежде чем их выбрать, их необходимо прочитать(в условии выборки), а чтение заблокировано SELECT FOR UPDATE`ом. Сейчас еще приведу код.

Comment: Хм. Забавная грабля в innodb, как-то даже не ожидал. Postgresql на не пересекающихся условиях не лочится. При том innodb лочится просто на pk in (1,3) если pk = 2 занят в другой транзакции. Хм.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В итоге после проведения нескольких нагрузочных тестов оптимальным оказался вариант, не использующий временной таблицы(каждый раз пересоздается, занимая основное время), но использующий блокировку для обновления.

Сначала все необходимые записи обновляются с установкой "ключа" выборки в виде хэша SHA-256(алгоритм не принципиален), затем все записи с установленным хэшом выбираются, но уже после завершения транзакции. Работает решение довольно быстро и с минимальными блокировками.

Важно также отметить, что данные из вью `availablePublicUnitsView` выбираются, предварительно сортируясь в случайном порядке(ORDER BY RAND), сводя блокировки почти к нулю.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE select_and_reserve_units(
    IN unitsCount INT,
    IN mediaId VARCHAR(40),
    IN reservationHash BINARY(64))
BEGIN

START TRANSACTION ;

    UPDATE units SET reserved=true, last_usage_time=NOW(), reservation_hash=reservationHash
    WHERE id IN (

        SELECT units.id
        FROM availablePublicUnitsView units
            LEFT JOIN media_info
                ON units.id=media_info.unit_id AND media_info.media_id=mediaId
        WHERE media_info.media_id IS NULL    
        FOR UPDATE

    ) LIMIT unitsCount;

COMMIT ;

SELECT unit.id AS id, unit.authkey AS authkey FROM units
WHERE reservation_hash=reservationHash AND reserved=true;

END;//
```

> P.S видимо, пора переходить на PostgreSQL...

Answer (score 1):

Я так поняла, нужно запретить параллельное выполнение этих запросов над одними и теми же записями?

Попробуйте изменить уровень изоляции. При этом используя SELECT FOR UPDATE.

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

READ UNCOMMITTED - разрешает другим чтение данных, даже если транзакция не подтверждена.

Либо REPEATABLE READ - должна блокировать только изменяемые строки.

Comment: Слышал про уровни изоляций, но по сути, тот, что стоит в mysql по дефолту и есть самый подходящий. В целом, картина везде одна и та же - https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEb3p.png - это, например, с READ UNCOMMITTED

Comment: Да, что-то не вникла, видимо, до конца в суть вопроса.

Comment: Но все же попробуйте READ UNCOMMITTED. Единственное, чтобы вторая транзакция не выбирала записи, занятые другой транзакцией, было бы неплохо, чтобы TempTable была видна всем транзакциям. Записывать туда id, authkey и номер транзакции. А после UPDATE удалять соответствующие записи. Правда на кривой костыль это похоже...

Comment: Может читали, но вдруг. Может вот эта статья поможет https://habrahabr.ru/post/150075/